# Use Stylus with Sails JS 0.10

Tags: css, node.js, sails.js, stylus

Starting to use Sails with Jade template is easy with the command:

```
sails new app --template=jade
```

How to add Stylus as default CSS preprocessor? (**with the latest Sails version**)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't able to find a better way to add Stylus to the latest Sails, than using grunt:

- Add grunt-contrib-stylus to project dependencies:

  ```
  npm install grunt-contrib-stylus --save
  ```
- Create a new grunt task stylus.js under tasks/config directory:

  ```
  module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.config.set('stylus', {
      dev: {
          files: [{
              expand: true,
              cwd: 'assets/styles/',
              src: ['importer.styl'],        //Edit this to match your files
              dest: '.tmp/public/styles/',
              ext: '.css'
          }]
      }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-stylus');

  };
  ```

Task will be executed automatically on `sails lift`, check result in .tmp/public/styles

Answer (score 3):

Its a few step process, first add
First npm install grunt-contrib-stylus then create a file /tasks/config/stylus.js and add:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

grunt.config.set('stylus', {
    dev: {
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: 'assets/styles/',
            src: ['style.styl'],
            dest: '.tmp/public/styles/',
            ext: '.css'
        }]
    }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-stylus');
```

};

then add, 'stylus:dev' to /tasks/register/compileAssets.js && syncAssets.js
after that add 'styl' to /task/register/copy.js for files to ignore

And it should all work, this is my first stackoverflow answer xD

Answer (score 2):

Go to `tasks/config` and add a `stylus.js` file with the following code:

```
module.exports = function(grunt){

    grunt.config.set('stylus', {
        dev: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'assets/styles/',
                src: ['main.styl'],
                dest: '.tmp/public/styles/',
                ext: '.css'
            }]
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-stylus');

}
```

Then go to `tasks/register` (which what previous answers missed) and add in both `syncAssets.js` and `compileAsset.js` where relevant:

```
'stylus:dev'
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this [pull](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/pull/371) it looks like it's already built into sails.

If it doesn't work automatically then it can probably be configured in the gruntfile.

Comment: Your link is really really old, 7 May 2013, maybe we can expect something more elegant like the "--template" option!